# Unreachable Statement After For Loop with If Statement

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an assignment that is very basic but it's all-new ground for me still. The program is supposed to ask the user(s) to enter their name, surname, grade, and subject. If the subject is not IT their input gets set aside. However, if the subject entered is IT their name, surname and grade will be used later on again to display a message that looks as followed:

[DisplayedMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scepN.png)

The information can differ depending on what the user(s) entered. Now the question comes in. I typed the code correctly but at the end where I display the message using JOptionPane it showed an error saying: "Unreachable Statement". (To clarify it happened next to the line of code) It was strange because it was almost identical to the memo of the assignment yet it had the error. It might have been the Netbeans being confused in a way but I redid the assignment at home and it worked as it should seen here:

```
    String name, surname, subject, message = "IT Learners:\n\n";
    int grade, counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Name Here: ");
        surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Surname Here: ");
        subject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Subject Here: ");
        grade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your "
                + "Grade Here: "));

        if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase("IT")) {
            message += name + " " + surname + " is in grade "
                    + grade + ".\n";
            counter++;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message + "There is a total of "
            + counter + " IT Learners.");
```

The next section of code is a copy of the code I wrote on the terminal during the period. I personally can't see the error and I came here to ask is it correct or is there a small error that I just can't seem to find.

Code I did at school:

```
    String name, surname, subject, message = "IT Learners:\n\n";
    int grade, counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Name Here: ");
        surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Surname Here: ");
        subject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Subject Here: ");
        grade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                ("Enter Your Grade Here: "));

        if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase("IT")) 
        {
            message += name + " " + surname + " is in grade "
                    + grade + ".\n";
            counter++;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message + "There is a total of "
            + counter + " IT Learners.");
```

It truly looks identical, was it just the Netbeans being confused or is there just a fine detail I am missing?

Entire code:

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    /**
    *
    * @author (My Name)
    */
    public class ITLearners {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String name, surname, subject, message = "IT Learners:\n\n";
    int grade, counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Name Here: ");
        surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Surname Here: ");
        subject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Subject Here: ");
        grade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your "
                + "Grade Here: "));

        if (subject.equalsIgnoreCase("IT")) {
            message += name + " " + surname + " " + " is in grade "
                    + grade + ".\n";
            counter++;
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message + "There is a total of "
            + counter + " IT Learners.");
}
}
```

Comment: Your code LGTM.

Comment: I think you need to show the whole code. Or try [the suggestions here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/unreachable-statement-java-error-how-to-resolve-it/).

Comment: I have just tried and there are no errors. Your code works perfectly. Maybe the error is from Netbeans. Now, would you like to try to run and compile in the command-line?

Comment: I tried it with the one I redid at home and it came out the same, with no errors. After that I did it with the copy of the one I did at school and there were also no errors. I'm assuming something must have happened on the NetBeans on the terminal at school where I was working on it but it's still confusing how it shows no errors when three separate people tried it and it came out with no errors yet the terminal at school said it had an error. I'll ask the teacher about it first thing tomorrow when I have my IT period then I'll come back to you, hopefully with the solution.

Comment: Also try to check the version of Netbeans and its compiler. Hopefully that would help solve the problem

Comment: It is the same version as the one downloaded onto the school's device. The teacher directly shared the installation folders with us so we all have the same versions and so forward. I'll come back to you in the morning with the answer to this hopefully. Thank you so much for your help, it's truly appreciated~

Answer (score 1):

I feel quite silly right now. The problem in the code done at school was that an i in the for loop condition was a 1. Like this:

```
   for ( int i = 0; 1 < 3; i++; )
```

Lesson learned out of this: make sure you type everything correctly. With the 1 there I created an unintentionally infinite loop without realizing it. Thank you so much for the help, especially @AcidResin!